# Qsort based on a column in a c-string?

Tags: c++, c, qsort

A class project involves sorting an array of strings, with each string containing an equal number of columns like this:

```
Cartwright   Wendy    93
Williamson   Mark     81
Thompson     Mark     100
Anderson     John     76
Turner       Dennis   56
```

The program accepts a command-line argument for which column to sort on, and should print out the sorted strings unmodified.

I would like to use strtok to break up copies of each string into columns, and make structs for each line like this:

```
struct line {
    char * line;
    char column_to_sort_on[MAX_COLUMN];
}
```

My problem is in the comparison function pointer that qsort takes as an arg. If I understand correctly, the comparison function must take two const void pointers *to the items to be sorted*, and return an int. This means I can't pass pointers to structs into the comparison function because that is not what qsort will be sorting. I can't pass in the column number to sort on to the comparison function, because it can only take two args. How can I get around this to sort these strings based on specific columns?

**edit:** Sorting is limited to qsort or my own if I really want. Give the choice, I choose qsort. :)

**edit # 2:**The consensus seems to be either use a global variable for the column number, or just use qsort to sort an array of structs. I hadn't thought of just sorting the structs, and using the pointer in them to print out the original string. I think that is what I will do. Thanks for the help all!

Comment: Does the assignment say you have to pass an array of strings to qsort, or that the as a result a string array must be sorted, no matter what it takes? If the latter, you could sort an array of structs, and then reorder the string array according to the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the structs like this:

```
struct line {
    char * line;
    char column_to_sort_on[MAX_COLUMN];
}
...

line*  Lines[max_lines]; // here you store the structs

int
cmp_lines( const void *elem1, const void *elem2 )
{
    line*  line1 = *(line**)elem1;
    line*  line2 = *(line**)elem2;
    // do the comparisons
}

qsort(Lines, max_lines, sizeof(line*), cmp_lines);
```

Comment: @Jergason, I corrected a bug in my code (line1 & line2 values).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not limited to using qsort, you can use std::sort, with a functor object that stores the column number. If you have to use qsort, one quick and dirty solution would be to store the column number in a global variable and use that in the comparisson function.

Comment: I thought about storing it in a global variable, but would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Different comparator functions, all of which take the whole struct, but each uses only one column for comparation.

Comment: Wouldn't this comparator function necessitate sorting an array of structs? I though what I passed into the comparator function had to be the same as what qsort was sorting, and I would only like to sort the original array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

C++ or C?  Based on your tags, I assume it's C++.  Let's try STL way.

You should use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`.  `std::sort` can take not only function pointer (compared to its C alternative), but any *object* that can be called as a function.  You may know that class instances can be called as functions with `operator()`.  Then the solution is straightforward: create a "functor" class that will create different functions upon construction.  The sort call would then look like that:

```
std::sort(array, array+size, comparator(2 /* sort by column #2 */));
```

The functor class effectively creates a so-called "closure": a dynamically created functional object that has local variables, but doesn't share them with other functional objects created this way.  It would look like this:

```
class comparator{
  private: unsigned int field_n;
  public: comparator(unsigned int _field_n) : field_n(_field_n) {};
  public: int operator () (char const *  lhs, char const * rhs)
       { /* compare here fields with index field_n */ };
};
```

Note that instead of void pointers comparison "function" (i.e. the class instance you create) has `char *` parameters, so you don't bother yourself with type casting.

In C, unfortunately, you can't do this the other way than creating a global variable.