# using qsort causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, cstring

Well, as part of learning C++, my project has a restriction on it. I'm not allowed to use any libraries except the basic ones such as `<cstring>` and a few other necessities.

The project should take in input from a file that is an "n" number of columns of strings and be able to sort the output according to lexicographical ordering of any selected column. So for example, given the input

```
Cartwright   Wendy    93
Williamson   Mark     81
Thompson     Mark     100
Anderson     John     76
Turner       Dennis   56
```

It should sort them by column. And my search around StackOverflow returned a result from someone else who had to do the exact same project a few years ago too Hahaha [Qsort based on a column in a c-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449299/qsort-based-on-a-column-in-a-c-string)

But in my case I just use a global variable for the column and get on with life. My problem came in when I am implementing the compare function for qsort

In my main method I call

```
qsort (data, i, sizeof(char*), compare);
```

where data is a `char * data[]` and `i` is the number of lines to compare. (5 in this case)

Below is my code for the compare method

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b){
    char* line1 = new char[1000]; char* line2 = new char[1000];
    strcpy(line1, *((const char**) a));
    strcpy(line2, *((const char**) b));
    char* left = &(strtok(line1, " \t"))[column-1];
    char* right = &(strtok(line2, " \t"))[column-1];
    return strcmp(left, right);
}
```

the 1000s are because I just generalized (and did bad coding on purpose) to overgeneralize that no lines will be longer than 1000 characters.

What confuses me is that when I use the debugger in Eclipse, I can see that it it compares it successfully the first time, then on the second round, it has a segmentation fault when it tries to compare them.

I also tried to change the code for assigning left and right to what is below but that didn't help either

```
char* left = new char[100];
strcpy(left, &(strtok(line1, " \t"))[column-1]);
char* right = new char[100];
strcpy(right, &(strtok(line2, " \t"))[column-1]);
```

Please help me understand what is causing this segmentation fault. The first time it compares the two, left = "Williamson" and right = "Thompson". The second time it compares (and crashes trying) left = "Cartwright" and right = "Thompson"

Comment: You have memory leaks in `compare`! There are also potential buffer overruns all over the place.

Comment: `qsort` is C legacy. If you program in C++, use `std::sort`.

Comment: _"no lines will be longer than 1000 characters"_, unless they will.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that I have memory leaks, but I don't really know *HOW* to get rid of them. And I didn't know that would indirectly cause a Seg Fault either. Also, @n.m. as I stated above, I can't use any other libraries, I'm lucky to have permission to use qsort. My only other option is to write my own sorting algoritm.

Comment: (that part about the no lines longer than 1000 is something my teacher suggested so we don't have to spend more time with determining all the lengths of the lines and so forth) This is just a learning excercise that's not focused on safety in that regard

Comment: Could you elaborate about functions from which headers you are allowed to use? If it is only `<cstring>`, you cannot complete the assignment (`<cstring>` has no input functions, for example).

Comment: You are not allowed to use the C++ string class, any non-standard C++ libraries, or the classes and functions from the Standard Template Library (vector, list, map, set, etc.). Specifically, the following header files may not be used:

    <string> (but you are allowed to use <cstring>)
    <algorithm>
    <deque>
    <list>
    <map>
    <queue>
    <set>
    <stack>
    <vector>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* line1 = new char[1000]; char* line2 = new char[1000];
```

This is not good at all.  You're never freeing this, so you leak 2000 bytes every time your comparison function is called.  Eventually this will lead to low-memory conditions and `new` will throw.  (Or on Linux your process might get killed by the OOM-killer).  It's also not very efficient when you could just have said `char line1[1000]`, which is super-quick because it simply subtracts from the stack pointer rather than potentially traversing a free list or asking the kernel for more memory.

But really you could be doing the compare without modifying or copying the strings.  For example:

```
static int
is_end_of_token(char ch)
{
    // If the string has the terminating NUL character we consider it the end.
    // If it has the ' ' or '\t' character we also consider it the end.  This
    // accomplishes the same thing as your strtok call, but WITHOUT modifying
    // the source buffer.
    return (!ch || ch == ' ' || ch == '\t');
}

int
compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   const char *strA = *(const char**)a;
   const char *strB = *(const char**)b;

   // Loop while there is data left to compare...
   while (!is_end_of_token(*strA) && !is_end_of_token(*strB))
   {
      if (*strA < *strB)
         return -1;      // String on left is smaller
      else if (*strA > *strB)
         return 1;       // String on right is smaller
      ++strA;
      ++strB;
   }

   if (is_end_of_token(*strA) && is_end_of_token(*strB))
      return 0;    // both strings are finished, so they are equal.
   else if (is_end_of_token(*strA))
      return -1;   // left string has ended, but right string still has chars
   else
      return 1;    // right string has ended, but left string still has chars
}
```

But lastly...  You're using `std::string` you say?  Well, if that's the case, then assuming the memory passed to `qsort` is compatible with "`const char **`" is a little weird, and I would expect it to crash.  In that sense maybe what you should do something like:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *strA = ((const std::string*)a)->c_str();
    const char *strB = ((const std::string*)b)->c_str();

    // ...
}
```

But really, if you are using C++ and not C, you should use `std::sort`.

Comment: Yeah, we are "technically" using C++ but really, we are limited to only C libraries. I don't agree with this restriction, but I can't change it either. One requirement is that I CAN'T use std::string, so thats why everythings a old style cstring. But brilliant! I don't know why I was wasting my time trying to get the strcmp method to work the way I wanted it to. :D And I really like the is_end_of_token idea.

Comment: Hmm.. I think while this solves my segmentation fault problem, I still have another big problem to tackle to make this work and that modifing this so it compares not the entire string thats passed in but only the part in the one column. :/ Welp, maybe that'll be up soon as a different question :D